# How can I insert arrays into columns on a database table for my pyramid app?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, pickle

I am trying to create an sql (sqlite) database where users upload an stl file and the data (all the points, triangles, ect.)  is stored in a database so that it is permanently available. Is it possible to do this with a database with only two columns (three with the key): name (title for the url), and data (the array data)?

The data array is in the format: `[[[x1,y1,z1],....],[[v1,v2,v3],...]]`. All points are given first and then the triangles are defined through ordering of the points given. Can this array be stored in the database, and if so, what data type would it be (integer, string, ect.)?

Upon reading into this issue more, It seems that pickling would be a good way to go: http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

I am having trouble figuring out how to implement this. Should I just add pickle(data)?

Edit: upon further review, it seems like pickling introduces some security holes that do not exist if using JSON. Is it possible to simply call `jsondatastring=JSON.stringify(data)` and then save that to the database? If so, what would be the appropriate column type?

Comment: You say a "database"? What kind?

Comment: sqlalchemy I think. I am building off this tutorial: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/index.html

Comment: That's not a database - that's an ORM

Comment: so its an SQL database then

Comment: I think Jon is asking what RDBMS you're using. E.g. PostgreSQL has `ARRAY` type, while (most?) others don't, so the answer to your question depends on RDBMS that's in use.

Comment: ohh sorry, Its sqlite right now

Comment: so would switching  to PostgreSQL let me just dictate the array column type and input it directly, or would I still need to serialize somehow?

Comment: Well, if you only need to store the data and won't do any operations with it inside DB, SQLite and [`PickleType`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.PickleType) will do fine.

Comment: I don't think i need to do any operations with the data, just insert it when a file is uploaded and then read it when a template is rendered. Can you give me more indication on how to do this with PickleType in an answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is only to store the array in DB and work with it in your webapp code, SQLAlchemy's [`PickleType`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.PickleType) is a good choice. Pickling and unpickling will be done transparently for you:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import PickleType

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    array = Column(PickleType)

foo = Foo(name=u'bar', array=[1, 2, 3])
session.add(foo)
session.commit()

foo = session.query(Foo).filter_by(name=u'bar').one()
print foo.array
```

Comment: when I try and initialize the db, it gives me the error: PickleType is not defined. Where should I define it?

Comment: edit: I have realized that pickling isn't as appropriate as converting the array to a JSON string and serializing it that way. see the edits to the question

Comment: If you read the docs of `PickleType`, you should have seen the full name of the class: `class sqlalchemy.types.PickleType(...`. So, you need to import it from `sqlalchemy.types`. Or it can be imported from `sqlalchemy` like any other type. I have updated my answer to reflect that. Also it should be safe to store pickled data, since it's you who is saving it. What's unsafe is already pickled objects that come from untrusted sources.